# panning on linux conflicts with zooming

Tags: shortcut

so i recently switched to pop os, and i imported my keymap the problem is, the `view3d.zoom` is mapped to wheel in/out, but i also have `view3d.view_pan` mapped to ctrl/shift + wheel up/down on windows i never had any issues, but on pop os both commands get activated, maybe this is a 2.80 thing but the last build that i had worked (on windows), that was in july or so, this is a major problem for be because i rely on the panning for  moving in the viewport, since im not using blender often im not going to relearn it.

Comment: Is this on a laptop?  Do you have emulate 3 button mouse enabled?

Comment: on a desktop, i have a normal steel series (rival 100) mouse.

Comment: In blender 2.80 there are icons in the viewport that do these functions.  You can also use the +/- keys and ctrl + numkey to zoom and pan

Comment: i know,  but i literally can't move without panning i never realised that, its like not being able to use wasd or the arrow keys in a game, anyways thanks for taking the time to comment.